# Delay in Page Load ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2, httpwebresponse

I have an Web application(ASP.NET MVC5) hosted in the web server 1 which access the REST Service(WebAPI) hosted in the web server 2.

In my Web application, on click on the tab, call to the webAPI is made and it retrieves the data from SQL table(I m using EF5) which has 10 records.

I m experiencing considerable delay in the response for the first time and when i click the consecutive tabs, the response is faster like anything.
When I close the browser and opens the URL again immediately, the response time improves
When I open the URL after an hour or so , the response time is again high.

I could notice similar behaviour when i test the web service individually.

P.S : I m using bundling and minification as well. I m using Windows authentication and ASP.NET impersonation

Comment: When you debug this, where is the delay occurring?

Comment: Response from the DB is taking the time. But this doesnt happen for the second time. As i said, the data which i m retrieving is very small just 10 records.